# Database efficiency based on number of tables

Tags: mysql, database

For users like facebook they will have separate table for each users or all in a single table. Which will be efficient?

Comment: Applications like facebook, can not have separate table for each user. Usually they will having tables for each region which will have their users only.

Comment: so all users can be kept in a single table .it wont affect the efficiency?

Comment: Yes. If the number of users gets so high that scale starts to impinge on efficiency, then it's usual to break the structure into more tables, otherwise known as sharding. Horizontal partitioning is another method where entities are split across different tables or even databases. The trick is in knowing where to look for a given row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't work like that. The paradigm is to have tables that store information about groups of entities, such as companies, people, compact discs. Having a table per entity, i.e. one table for every user, doesn't really make sense, and would be very hard to use.